# Picture box just fades out instead of moving. (Broken movement system)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to make a game in Win forms using VB from scratch which i know is a bad idea but i like the challenge. Therefore i have been testing movement systems so i can choose my favourite , however i have ran into an issue as trying to move with a picture box as when i press the movement key the picture box just starts erasing the image in the direction i wanted to move until it disappears.

I am using

```
Public Class Form1
Dim RightM As Boolean
Dim LeftM As Boolean
Dim UpM As Boolean
Dim DownM As Boolean

Sub Movement()
    Do While UpM = True
        PictureBox1.Top += -5
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(20)
    Loop
    Do While LeftM = True
        PictureBox1.Left += -5
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(20)
    Loop
    Do While DownM = True
        PictureBox1.Top += 5
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(20)
    Loop
    Do While RightM = True
        PictureBox1.Left += 5
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(20)
    Loop
    Do While (UpM = True) And (RightM = True)
        PictureBox1.Top += -5
        PictureBox1.Left += 5
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(20)
    Loop
    Do While (UpM = True) And (LeftM = True)
        PictureBox1.Top += -5
        PictureBox1.Left += -5
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(20)
    Loop
    Do While (DownM = True) And (RightM = True)
        PictureBox1.Top += 5
        PictureBox1.Left += 5
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(20)
    Loop
    Do While (DownM = True) And (LeftM = True)
        PictureBox1.Top += 5
        PictureBox1.Left += -5
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        LeftM = True
        Movement()
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        RightM = True
        Movement()
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        UpM = True
        Movement()
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
        DownM = True
        Movement()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyUp(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyUp
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then
        LeftM = False
        Movement()
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then
        RightM = False
        Movement()
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then
        UpM = False
        Movement()
    ElseIf e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then
        DownM = False
        Movement()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: The Movement() method needs additional checks so you can't move the picturebox outside of the form's client area.  Walls so to speak.  Check Top and Left against 0, Bottom and Right against ClientSize.  The Do While loops are not correct either, they always move the pbox endlessly without any way to stop it.  As-is the pbox always disappears from sight.  A Timer is an easy way to implement a game loop.  Use Boolean variables that indicate movement direction, set them to True with KeyDown and False with KeyUp.   Google "windows forms game loop" to learn more.

Comment: Thanks very much I've been struggling for a while and didn't consider the problem to be with the while loops and thanks for the search term aswell. :)

Answer (score 0):

The question took me back to the Z80 days, I got a little nostalgic so decided to post a simplified answer.

```
'Position of PictureBox
Private Plocation As Point

'PictureBox Movement Boundries
Private XL As Integer 'X - Left
Private XR As Integer 'X - Right
Private YT As Integer 'Y - Top
Private YB As Integer 'Y - Bottom

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Set Boundries
    XL = 0
    XR = Me.ClientSize.Width - PictureBox1.Width
    YT = 0
    YB = Me.ClientSize.Height - PictureBox1.Height

    'Position PictureBox roughly in the centre of the Form
    Plocation = New Point((Me.ClientSize.Width / 2) - (PictureBox1.Width / 2), (Me.ClientSize.Height / 2) - (PictureBox1.Height / 2))
    PictureBox1.Location = Plocation
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    'Change X,Y depending on KeyPress
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.A Then Plocation.X -= 5
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.D Then Plocation.X += 5
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.W Then Plocation.Y -= 5
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.S Then Plocation.Y += 5

    'Check for X,Y boundries
    If Plocation.X < XL Then Plocation.X = XL
    If Plocation.X > XR Then Plocation.X = XR
    If Plocation.Y < YT Then Plocation.Y = YT
    If Plocation.Y > YB Then Plocation.Y = YB

    'Update Position
    PictureBox1.Location = Plocation
End Sub
```

I'm intentionally checking all key presses one after another, helps with diagonal movements. It's a little choppy and basic but may give you some ideas. Happy programming...